# Operator '+' cannot be applied to int,'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SerializedString'

Tags: java, android, android-thread

I'm facing Operator '+' cannot be applied to int,'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SerializedString' Error in run method of a thread.
Here's the code block

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ActivityHome.this.scanning_following.setText(ActivityHome.this.mapB.size()
                            + MinimalPrettyPrinter.DEFAULT_ROOT_VALUE_SEPARATOR
                            + ActivityHome.this.getResources().getString(R.string.following)
                            + " scanned");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `MinimalPrettyPrinter.DEFAULT_ROOT_VALUE_SEPARATOR` or `ActivityHome.this.getResources().getString(R.string.following)` is not a `java.lang.String`, so you can't apply `+` operator to it.

You can easily convert them to `java.util.String` by calling `toString()` (this is assuming `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SerializedString` has a meaningful implementation of `toString()`):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ActivityHome.this.scanning_following.setText(ActivityHome.this.mapB.size()
                            + MinimalPrettyPrinter.DEFAULT_ROOT_VALUE_SEPARATOR.toString()
                            + ActivityHome.this.getResources().getString(R.string.following).toString()
                            + " scanned");
                }
            });
```